# make installer for jar file

Tags: jar, installation

I was creating jar file, with fonts (.ttf) and with additional jar file, now I wont make installer which is check jdk or jre version during the install and install it. Also install (distribute) my jar file.

is any free soft for making installer.
thank you for advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am found solution and I wont to publish.

1. in NetBeans IDE -> Build Deployment-> Enable native Packaging in Project Menu.
2. download isetup-5.5.5 from http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php